# Portlet navigation

Tags: liferay, jsr286, gatein

We are evaluating using JSR-286 portlets for our next project. Users will be able to build an web app with our hosted service. Each user will get a webiste on our portlet server. One of our scenarios is:

- The user places our "table portlet" one page, he chooses the id free
- The user places one of our "detail portlet"s on another page
- When some one clicks on a "detail buton" on the "table portlet" he should be navigated to the "detail portlet"

Is there some way to get the urls of the "detail portlet"s in the "table portlet". Something like `List<URL> PortletUtil.getPortletURLs(String portletType)`?

We don't want the user has to configure a target URL in the "table portlet", to avoid broken links if the detail page URL is changed.

We have not decided yet which portlet server to use (if at all), so server specific solutions are ok.

Comment: For directing to the details portlet,to have the specific URL,we need to be sure that the portlet page name remains same as the page layout id will be calculated on the same basis.So are we looking to have the same page name?If not then we need to be sure that the details portlet is only on one of the pages,to get the specific layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portlet specification says nothing about pages. From a JSR-286 standpoint, the answer to your question is "No".

You also tag Liferay and GateIn, which have proprietary APIs. Without going into detail, in Liferay you'd look for the "layout" (which is the API name for a page) within a site (API name: group). You'll use LayoutService or LayoutLocalService for this task. Depending on your usecase it might be eating into your performance to constantly look up pages, so you might want to cache results (but measure first if it indeed is a relevant performance hit). If you don't want to configure the page explicitly, you also need to decide how to react if different pages contain the same detail portlet.

On GateIn's API, I can't give any hints.